# How to use autoIndex in mongoose / mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb with mongoose in my project. I am trying to use text indexes so i can implement a search functionality. I have set auotIndex option to true but i still get the following error "MongoError: text index required for $text query" this indicates text indexes have not been generated and therefor autoIndex is not working if i am not mistaken.

By the way i know that autoIndex should not be in production ready applications because it is heavy but the project i am working on is just for learning purposes.

```
// Database start upp
(async () => {
    const DB_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/photogram-db";

    const DB_SETTINGS = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        autoIndex: true
    };

    await mongoose.connect(DB_URI, DB_SETTINGS);
})();


// Person model / schema
const PersonSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    username: String,
});

PersonSchema.index({
    firstName: "text",
    lastName: "text",
    username: "text"
});

const PersonModel = model("Person", PersonSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Text index creation takes some time, so I guess it's not ready when you search with text?
Maybe you can try to listen to the index event when the index is done.

```
 PersonModel.on('index', function(error) {
      console.log('index is finished');
  });
```

Comment: You are right the index creation is done after the error. Then how do i fix it, do i need to write script that creates the index in before hand, if so how do i write the script or does a script like that already exists

Comment: if you need to create the collection every time your app starts, you may need to do the text query in the index event handler. if not, you can Mongo console, connect to database, create the text indexes, then start your app without the indexing part. This problem may be unique for text indexes, as for other type of indexes you can still do the query even without index being built.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i solved the problem by creating the indexes directly after the db connection and before the app starts, i don't know if it is the right way or the good way to do it.